# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/conversationLogs/42779251.json'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, mod-wsgi, ubuntu-18.04

I am running trying to deploy a flask app on ubuntu using this blog

[Deploy a flask app on ubuntu VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

the static code runs smoothly but when I integrated my code into it I faced a lot of issues and finally, I'm stuck with this final one where I want to read a son and if JSON is not present then create it but getting the same error

**[wsgi:error] [pid 17042:tid 140183924913920] [client x.127.x.235:10100] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/Json/abcs.json'**

I have tried the following steps from various StackOverflow suggestions:

1. Sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www
2. using base_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(**file**)) then adding /Json/abcs.json in the path to access the file.

Nothing has worked for me

Comment: Maybe find out who the 'user' that is running the apache service is? And then making sure that 'user' has access/onwership of the file? https://serverfault.com/questions/125865/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as

Comment: Have you checked if SELinux in enabled on the system?